# crawler to follow links and get information from links python

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

Guys I need to make a bot that will collect some information from links, it will first go to this link https://www.mediktor.com/pt-br/glossario and get the links to all the diseases and then go one by one and get their information like description, epidemiology, symptoms and etc. I came up with this code where it can get the links but it doesn't return anything when I try to access them and get the information

```
import scrapy
import time
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import json


class DicionarioSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'dicionario'
    allowed_domains = ['www.mediktor.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.mediktor.com/']

    def start_requests(self):
        url = "https://www.mediktor.com/pt-br/glossario"
        options = Options()
        options.headless = True
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(10)

        doencas = driver.find_elements(
            By.XPATH, "//a[@class='mdk-dictionary-list__glossary-item']")
        for doenca in doencas:
            url = doenca.get_attribute('href')
            yield scrapy.Request(url)
        driver.quit()

    def parse(self, response):
        urls = response.css(
            '.mdk-dictionary-list__glossary-item a::attr(href)')
        for url in urls:
            yield response.follow(url.get(), callback=self.parse_info)

    def parse_info(self, response):
        contents = response.css('div.page-glossary-detail__main-content')
        for desc in response.css('div.mdk-conclusion-detail__main-description'):
            desc = response.css('p ::text').getall()
        yield {
            'desc': desc
        }
        for content in contents:
            yield{
                'name': content.css(
                    'div.mdk-conclusion-detail__main-title ::text').get().strip(),
                'espec': content.css(
                    'div.mdk-ui-list-item__text mdc-list-item__text span::text').strip()
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the data is dynamically loaded, you can get all possible IDs, and one by one go through and get information on them. In my example, getting the first one from the list, and a huge JSON from which you will get all the necessary data. I had to cut off part of it because of the character limit

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_auth_code():
    url = "https://www.mediktor.com/vendor.js"
    response = requests.get(url)
    start_index = response.text.index('APP_API_AUTH_CODE:"', 0) + len('APP_API_AUTH_CODE:"')
    end_index = response.text.index('"', start_index)
    return response.text[start_index:end_index]


def get_auth_token_and_device_id():
    url = "https://euapi01.mediktor.com/backoffice/services/login"
    payload = "{\"useCache\":0,\"apiVersion\":\"4.1.1\",\"appVersion\":\"8.7.0\"," \
              "\"appId\":null,\"deviceType\":\"WEB\",\"deviceToken\":null,\"language\":\"en_EN\"," \
              "\"timezoneRaw\":180,\"authTokenRefreshExpiresIn\":null}"
    headers = {
        'authorization': f'Basic {get_auth_code()}',
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    }
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    return response.json()['authToken'], response.json()['deviceId']


def get_conclusion_list(auth_token, device_id):
    url = "https://euapi01.mediktor.com/backoffice/services/conclusionList"
    payload = "{\"useCache\":168,\"apiVersion\":\"4.1.1\",\"appVersion\":\"8.7.0\"" \
              ",\"appId\":null,\"deviceType\":\"WEB\",\"deviceToken\":null,\"language\":\"pt_BR\"," \
              "\"timezoneRaw\":180,\"deviceId\":\"" + device_id + "\"}"
    headers = {
        'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'authorization': f'Bearer {auth_token}',
        'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
    }
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    return [conclusionId['conclusionId'] for conclusionId in response.json()['conclusions']]


def get_details(conclusionId, auth_token, device_id):
    url = "https://euapi01.mediktor.com/backoffice/services/conclusionDetail"
    payload = "{\"useCache\":0,\"apiVersion\":\"4.1.1\",\"appVersion\":\"8.7.0\"," \
              "\"appId\":null,\"deviceType\":\"WEB\",\"deviceToken\":null,\"language\":\"pt_BR\"," \
              "\"timezoneRaw\":180,\"deviceId\":\"" + device_id + "\"," \
              "\"conclusionId\":\"" + conclusionId + "\"," \
              "\"conclusionTemplate\":\"conclusion_description_body\",\"includeActions\":true}"
    headers = {
        'authorization': f'Bearer {auth_token}',
        'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
    }
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    return response.text


auth_token, device_id = get_auth_token_and_device_id()
conclusion_list = get_conclusion_list(auth_token, device_id)
for conclusion in conclusion_list[:1]:
    print(get_details(conclusion, auth_token, device_id))
```

OUTPUT:

```
{"conclusion":{"conclusionId":"e61a5a5b-2587-48ee-af32-49331f659810","description":"Pitiríase rósea de Gibert (Pediatria)","descriptionMap":{"it_IT":["Pitiriasi rosea di Gibert (Pediatria)"],"el_GR":["Ροδόχρους πιτυρίαση Gilbert (Παιδιατρική)"],"fr_BE":["Pityriasis rosé de Gibert (Pédiatrie)"],"nl_BE":["Pityriasis rosea van Gibert (Pediatrie)"],"pt_BR":["Pitiríase rósea de Gibert (Pediatria)"],"fr_FR":["Pityriasis rosé de Gibert (Pédiatrie)"],"ca_ES":["Pitiriasi rosada de Gibert (Pediatria)"],"de_DE":["Röschenflechte - Pityriasis rosea (Kinderheilkunde)"],"en_US":["Pityriasis rosea Gibert (Pediatrics)"],"es_MX":["Pitiriasis rosada de Gibert (Pediatría)"],"zh_CN":["玫瑰糠疹 (儿科)"],"es_ES":["Pitiriasis rosada de Gibert (Pediatría)"],"en_EN":["Pityriasis rosea Gibert (Paediatrics)"],"pt_PT":["Pitiríase rósea de Gibert (Pediatria)"]},"lastEdited":1650459591108,"frequency":0.2,"frequencyEnum":0,"descriptionHeaderImage":"https://api.mediktor.com/backoffice/downloads/File.Download?userId=04c35e41-6a8b-4541-44a3-cc20230ebdff&type=media&id=45c9a541-dbfc-41fe-8b73-76d021b245a1&d=1596042153781&b&l=1920","descriptionExtendedManagerFullName":"Dr Maria Trabazo","lastEditedGlobalFormattedToDay":"20/05/2022","severity":0.05,"severityEnum":0,"icd9":"696.3","icd10":"L42","specialties":["Dermatologia","Pediatria"],"specialtyIdList":["11","32"],"hasDescriptionExtended":true,"images":["https://api.mediktor.com/backoffice/downloads/File.Download?userId=04c35e41-6a8b-4541-44a3-cc20230ebdff&type=media&id=45c9a541-dbfc-41fe-8b73-76d021b245a1&d=1596042153781&b&l=1920","https://api.mediktor.com/backoffice/downloads/File.Download?userId=04c35e41-6a8b-4541-44a3-cc20230ebdff&type=media&id=9cd01ae5-383b-481a-92a8-518fe4dc3a9d&d=1560963312374&b&l=1920","https://api.mediktor.com/backoffice/downloads/File.Download?userId=04c35e41-6a8b-4541-44a3-cc20230ebdff&type=media&id=02202660-d437-4f91-b0c1-3cd35efb6663&d=1500652985149&b&l=1920"],"mediaFileList":[{"mediaURL":"https://api.mediktor.com/backoffice/downloads/File.Download?userId=04c35e41-6a8b-4541-44a3-cc20230ebdff&type=media&id=45c9a541-dbfc-41fe-8b73-76d021b245a1&d=1596042153781&b&l=1920","copyright":"© Copyright TeckelMedical","description":"Pitiríase rósea de Gibert","type":1},{"mediaURL":"https://api.mediktor.com/backoffice/downloads/File.Download?userId=04c35e41-6a8b-4541-44a3-cc20230ebdff&type=media&id=9cd01ae5-383b-481a-92a8-518fe4dc3a9d&d=1560963312374&b&l=1920","copyright":"© Copyright BIODERMA PRO","description":"Pitiríase de Gibert","type":1},{"mediaURL":"https://api.mediktor.com/backoffice/downloads/File.Download?userId=04c35e41-6a8b-4541-44a3-cc20230ebdff&type=media&id=02202660-d437-4f91-b0c1-3cd35efb6663&d=1500652985149&b&l=1920","copyright":"© Copyright TeckelMedical","description":"Pitiríase rósea de Gibert","type":1}],"actionList":[],"specialtyList":[{"categoryId":"11","specialtyId":"11","name":"Dermatologia","descriptionExtended":"<p>Especialidade que estuda, diagnostica e trata doen&ccedil;as da pele.</p>\n\n<p>Existem subespecialidades da dermatologia como, por exemplo, a dermatologia pedi&aacute;trica, dermatologia cosm&eacute;tica, etc.</p>","image":"https://api.mediktor.com/backoffice/downloads/File.Download?userId=04c35e41-6a8b-4541-44a3-cc20230ebdff&type=media&id=bfbba59f-806d-43a7-a5c4-cbde2210143b&d=1477780137091&b&l=960","propertyValueList":[{"propertyId":"b9d82cad-1911-4fb6-b764-21fc25cf0341","name":"Código de especialidade do Medicare","value":"7"},{"propertyId":"593639e8-6423-4597-8801-3e362c1f9b7d","name":"OMC Id","value":"16"},{"propertyId":"cb6e1fc1-a673-4eab-8dec-4a483a473818","name":"SNOMED","value":"394582007"}],"isActive":true,"lastEdited":1657546400463,"typeMask":1048580,"isExclusive":false,"isSpecialty":true,"isHomeSection":false,"shownOrder":100,"tintColor":"#FF03A6A6","statements":[]},{"categoryId":"32","specialtyId":"32","name":"Pediatria","descriptionExtended":"<p>Especialidade que estuda, diagnostica, trata e previne doen&ccedil;as da inf&acirc;ncia.</p>\n\n<p>Engloba desde o nascimento at&eacute; a adolesc&ecirc;ncia, que, dependendo do pa&iacute;s, varia desde os&nbsp;16 aos 18 anos.</p>","image":"https://api.mediktor.com/backoffice/downloads/File.Download?userId=04c35e41-6a8b-4541-44a3-cc20230ebdff&type=media&id=b2dca339-eee3-479f-9545-67f6d9872cc2&d=1477779967750&b&l=960","propertyValueList":[{"propertyId":"b9d82cad-1911-4fb6-b764-21fc25cf0341","name":"Código de especialidade do Medicare","value":"37"},{"propertyId":"593639e8-6423-4597-8801-3e362c1f9b7d","name":"OMC Id","value":"2"}],"isActive":true,"lastEdited":1657546400456,"typeMask":4,"isExclusive":false,"isSpecialty":true,"isHomeSection":false,"shownOrder":100,"tintColor":"#FF03A6A6","statements":[]}],"descriptionExtended":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.2//EN\"\r\n \"http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/xhtml-mobile12.dtd\">\r\n <html>\r\n <head>\r\n <meta name=viewport content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">\r\n <meta charset=\"utf-8\" /> \r\n <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />\r\n <style>\r\n \tbody\r\n \t{\r\n \t\tmargin:0;\r\n \t\tpadding:0;\r\n \t\tfont-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;\r\n \t}\r\n \t.imgheadercontainer\r\n \t{\t\r\n \t\twidth:100%;\r\n \t}\r\n \t.imgheader\r\n \t{\r\n \t\twidth:100%;\r\n \t}\r\n \t.descriptionscontainer\r\n \t{\t\r\n \t\tpadding:10px;\r\n \t\ttext-align:justify;\r\n \t}\r\n \t.attachment_thumbnail\r\n \t{\r\n \t\twidth:20%;\r\n \t\theight:auto;\r\n \t}\r\n </style>\r\n </head>\r\n <body>\r\n \r\n   <div class=\"descriptionscontainer\">\r\n <p>\n<p>Erup&ccedil;&atilde;o benigna na pele que se caracteriza por placas eritematosas, que costumam come&ccedil;ar no peito, costas e/ou abd&ocirc;men&nbsp;e podem se espalhar para o resto do corpo. Pode surgir em qualquer idade, mas predomina em crian&ccedil;as maiores e adultos jovens.</p>\n<p>A causa &eacute; desconhecida, mas acredita-se ser devido a uma infec&ccedil;&atilde;o viral. N&atilde;o &eacute; contagiosa entre pessoas.</p>\n<p>Os sintomas iniciais s&atilde;o semelhantes a um resfriado comum: dor de cabe&ccedil;a, febre, dor de garganta e/ou congest&atilde;o nasal. Segue-se o aparecimento de uma grande les&atilde;o cut&acirc;nea escamosa e arredondada, que em poucos dias se estende na forma de les&otilde;es menores pelo resto do corpo. Geralmente, estas les&otilde;es provocam intensa coceira.</p>\n<p>O diagn&oacute;stico &eacute; cl&iacute;nico, baseado na anamnese e exame f&iacute;sico. Se existe d&uacute;vida quanto ao diagn&oacute;stico, pode-se complementar o estudo com exame de sangue e biopsia.</p>\n<p>O tratamento baseia-se em aliviar a coceira com anti-histam&iacute;nicos e/ou lo&ccedil;&otilde;es; rem&eacute;dios caseiros, como banhos com &aacute;gua morna, podem ajudar a diminuir a coceira. O uso de fototerapia pode acelerar o desaparecimento das les&otilde;es cut&acirc;neas. Por &uacute;ltimo, empregam-se antivirais nos casos claramente associados a uma virose.</p>\n<p>Se voc&ecirc; tem algum destes sintomas ou eles ainda n&atilde;o desapareceram 12 semanas ap&oacute;s o diagn&oacute;stico, consulte um especialista.</p>\n</p>\r\n </div>\r\n <br/>\r\n   <div class=\"imgheadercontainer\">\r\n <img class=\"imgheader\" src=\"https://api.mediktor.com/backoffice/downloads/File.Download?userId=04c35e41-6a8b-4541-44a3-cc20230ebdff&type=media&id=45c9a541-dbfc-41fe-8b73-76d021b245a1&d=1596042153781&b&l=1920\"/>\r\n </div>\r\n <br/>\r\n  <div class=\"descriptionscontainer\">\r\n   \r\n   \r\n   \r\n   \r\n   \r\n   \r\n    <h4>Refer&ecirc;ncias</h4>\r\n <p>\n<ol>\n\t<li>J. M Moragas. Manifestaciones cut&aacute;neas de las enfermedades internas. Interpretaci&oacute;n de las alteraciones en la piel. Farreras Rozman. Medicina Interna. Volumen I. Duod&eacute;cima edici&oacute;n. 707:719.</li>\n\t<li>T. J. Lwley, K.B. Yancey. Trastornos de la piel. Valoraci&oacute;n del paciente con trastornos cut&aacute;neos. Harrison. Principios de Medicina Interna. Volumen I. Decimonovena edici&oacute;n. 339:352.</li>\n\t<li>I. L&oacute;pez, C. Dur&aacute;n, M.M. S&aacute;ez, L. Orozco, C. Palacios, R. Ruiz. Pitiriasis rosada: un exantema que debe ser reconocido por el m&eacute;dico de primer contacto. Estudio de 30 casos. Acta Pedi&aacute;tr Mex 2014;35:289-294.</li>\n\t<li>UpToDate [Internet]. Waltham. 2017. Pityriasis rosea; [citado el 20 de julio de 2017]. Disponible en: http://www.uptodate.com/contents/pityriasis-rosea?source=search_result&amp;search=pitiriasis+rosada&amp;selectedTitle=1~1</li>\n</ol>\n</p>\r\n <br/>\r\n  \r\n   <h4>Palavras-chave</h4>\r\n <p>pitir&iacute;ase rosea, v&iacute;rus do herpes 7, pitir&iacute;ase r&oacute;sea de Gilbert, pitir&iacute;ase rosea gibert</p>\r\n <br/>\r\n  \r\n \r\n  \r\n <br/>\r\n <br/>\r\n \r\n <p style=\"float:right;\"><b><small>\r\n  \r\n    Autor: Dr Maria Trabazo\r\n <br/>\r\n   \r\n   \r\n     Revisado: 20/05/2022\r\n <br/>\r\n  \r\n &copy; TeckelMedical 2022</small></b></p>\r\n \r\n </div>\r\n \r\n </body>\r\n </html>","descriptionSummary":"<p>Erup&ccedil;&atilde;o benigna na pele que se caracteriza por placas eritematosas, que costumam come&ccedil;ar no peito, costas e/ou abd&ocirc;men&nbsp;e podem se espalhar para o resto do corpo. Pode surgir em qualquer idade, mas predomina em crian&ccedil;as maiores e adultos jovens.</p>\n\n<p>A causa &eacute; desconhecida, mas acredita-se ser devido a uma infec&ccedil;&atilde;o viral. N&atilde;o &eacute; contagiosa entre pessoas.</p>\n\n<p>Os sintomas iniciais s&atilde;o semelhantes a um resfriado comum: dor de cabe&ccedil;a, febre, dor de garganta e/ou congest&atilde;o nasal. Segue-se o aparecimento de uma grande les&atilde;o cut&acirc;nea escamosa e arredondada, que em poucos dias se estende na forma de les&otilde;es menores pelo resto do corpo. Geralmente, estas les&otilde;es provocam intensa coceira.</p>\n\n<p>O diagn&oacute;stico &eacute; cl&iacute;nico, baseado na anamnese e exame f&iacute;sico. Se existe d&uacute;vida quanto ao diagn&oacute;stico, pode-se complementar o estudo com exame de sangue e biopsia.</p>\n\n<p>O tratamento baseia-se em aliviar a coceira com anti-histam&iacute;nicos e/ou lo&ccedil;&otilde;es; rem&eacute;dios caseiros, como banhos com &aacute;gua morna, podem ajudar a diminuir a coceira. O uso de fototerapia pode acelerar o desaparecimento das les&otilde;es cut&acirc;neas. Por &uacute;ltimo, empregam-se antivirais nos casos claramente associados a uma virose.</p>\n\n<p>Se voc&ecirc; tem algum destes sintomas ou eles ainda n&atilde;o desapareceram 12 semanas ap&oacute;s o diagn&oacute;stico, consulte um especialista.</p>","descriptionKeywords":"pitiríase rosea, vírus do herpes 7, pitiríase rósea de Gilbert, pitiríase rosea gibert","descriptionBibliography":"<ol>\n\t<li>J. M Moragas. Manifestaciones cut&aacute;neas de las enfermedades internas. Interpretaci&oacute;n de las alteraciones en la piel. Farreras Rozman. Medicina Interna. Volumen I. Duod&eacute;cima edici&oacute;n. 707:719.</li>\n\t<li>T. J. Lwley, K.B. Yancey. Trastornos de la piel. Valoraci&oacute;n del paciente con trastornos cut&aacute;neos. Harrison. Principios de Medicina Interna. Volumen I. Decimonovena edici&oacute;n. 339:352.</li>\n\t<li>I. L&oacute;pez, C. Dur&aacute;n, M.M. S&aacute;ez, L. Orozco, C. Palacios, R. Ruiz. Pitiriasis rosada: un exantema que debe ser reconocido por el m&eacute;dico de primer contacto. Estudio de 30 casos. Acta Pedi&aacute;tr Mex 2014;35:289-294.</li>\n\t<li>UpToDate [Internet]. Waltham. 2017. Pityriasis rosea; [citado el 20 de julio de 2017]. Disponible en: http://www.uptodate.com/contents/pityriasis-rosea?source=search_result&amp;search=pitiriasis+rosada&amp;selectedTitle=1~1</li>\n</ol>","genderEpidemiologyDescription":"Encontrado igualmente em ambos os sexos.","ageEpidemiologyDescription":"Ocorre até a idade de 18 anos.","epidemiologyDescription":"Encontrado igualmente em ambos os sexos.\n Ocorre até a idade de 18 anos.\n","authorDescription":"Dr Maria Trabazo","copyrightDescription":"&copy; TeckelMedical 2022","propertyValueList":[{"propertyId":"dd165ff4-e848-4b3e-b7bb-cec77117b8a1","name":"CID9","value":"696.3"},{"propertyId":"b0c0d503-cc2a-4416-a53c-e10f465d4bf9","name":"CID9 revisado","value":"b0c0d503-cc2a-4416-a53c-e10f465d4bf9:reviewed"},{"propertyId":"05c21681-3ff1-4c8c-bb0a-beba62984b6d","name":"CID10","value":"L42"},{"propertyId":"85c59095-eefe-469e-a6c4-faa7bf67d6a1","name":"CID10 revisado","value":"85c59095-eefe-469e-a6c4-faa7bf67d6a1:reviewed"},{"propertyId":"4a637756-3fd4-419b-9c84-31075135d8a3","name":"ICD11","value":"EA10"},{"propertyId":"f29c2d86-81fb-4ece-8375-bc1d89545af6","name":"CID11 revisado","value":"f29c2d86-81fb-4ece-8375-bc1d89545af6:reviewed"},{"propertyId":"cb6e1fc1-a673-4eab-8dec-4a483a473818","name":"SNOMED","value":"77252004"},{"propertyId":"b811b9b7-2aba-422b-9794-ae4633c837d9","name":"SNOMED revisado","value":"b811b9b7-2aba-422b-9794-ae4633c837d9:reviewed"}],"symptomsOrSigns":[{"statement":{"statementId":"207","description":"Você tem uma erupção cutânea?","descriptionShort":"Erupção cutânea","images":["https://api.mediktor.com/backoffice/downloads/File.Download?userId=04c35e41-6a8b-4541-44a3-cc20230ebdff&type=media&id=a00ba8a5-fc16-40cc-813b-f752548a93a0&d=1605264931409&b&l=1920","https://api.mediktor.com/backoffice/downloads/File.Download?userId=04c35e41-6a8b-4541-44a3-cc20230ebdff&type=media&id=b8027d03-fcc9-4dd0-901e-66b79f170268&d=1477638095996&b&l=1920"],"mediaFileList":[{"mediaURL":"https://api.mediktor.com/backoffice/downloads/File.Download?userId=04c35e41-6a8b-4541-44a3-cc20230ebdff&type=media&id=a00ba8a5-fc16-40cc-813b-f752548a93a0&d=1605264931409&b&l=1920","copyright":"© Copyright TeckelMedical","type":1},{"mediaURL":"https://api.mediktor.com/backoffice/downloads/File.Download?userId=04c35e41-6a8b-4541-44a3-cc20230ebdff&type=media&id=b8027d03-fcc9-4dd0-901e-66b79f170268&d=1477638095996&b&l=1920","copyright":"© Copyright TeckelMedical","type":1}],"questionType":0,"descriptionLarge":"Zona da pele avermelhada, com manchas e/ou borbulhas, geralmente irritada.","descriptionExtended":"Zona da pele avermelhada, com manchas e/ou borbulhas, geralmente irritada.","hasDescriptionExtended":true,"categoryIdList":[],"propertyValueList":[{"propertyId":"9732a98d-86c1-4df9-9522-bc479417e25d","name":"CID10 +Genéricos","value":"R21"},{"propertyId":"ea24aba3-468d-42ba-8cf1-c95d1322aee6","name":"CID9 + Genérico","value":"782.1"},"statementId":"d5f8e344-3c7a-491f-8f67-5e6901c4dc6b","positiveProbability":1.0,"conclusionId":"e61a5a5b-2587-48ee-af32-49331f659810","lastEdited":1522923311633,"isActive":true,"obligatory":false},{"statement":{"statementId":"37","description":"Sua pele coça?","descriptionShort":"Coceira na pele","images":["https://api.mediktor.com/backoffice/downloads/File.Download?userId=04c35e41-6a8b-4541-44a3-cc20230ebdff&type=media&id=f39068f9-d8a6-4d07-842f-2e1216550c77&d=1563813028540&b&l=1920"],"mediaFileList":[{"mediaURL":"https://api.mediktor.com/backoffice/downloads/File.Download?userId=04c35e41-6a8b-4541-44a3-cc20230ebdff&type=media&id=f39068f9-d8a6-4d07-842f-2e1216550c77&d=1563813028540&b&l=1920","copyright":"© Copyright TeckelMedical","description":"Comichão na pele","type":1}],"questionType":1,"descriptionLarge":"<p>Voc&ecirc; sente formigamento e/ou coceira em todo o corpo ou em parte dele, e tem vontade de co&ccedil;ar para aliviar a sensa&ccedil;&atilde;o.</p>","descriptionExtended":"<p>Voc&ecirc; sente formigamento e/ou coceira em todo o corpo ou em parte dele, e tem vontade de co&ccedil;ar para aliviar a sensa&ccedil;&atilde;o.</p>","hasDescriptionExtended":true,"categoryIdList":[],"propertyValueList":[{"propertyId":"9732a98d-86c1-4df9-9522-bc479417e25d","name":"CID10 +Genéricos","value":"L29.8"},{"propertyId":"ea24aba3-468d-42ba-8cf1-c95d1322aee6","name":"CID9 + Genérico","value":"698.8"},{"propertyId":"b0c0d503-cc2a-4416-a53c-e10f465d4bf9","name":"CID9 revisado","value":"b0c0d503-cc2a-4416-a53c-e10f465d4bf9:reviewed"},{"propertyId":"85c59095-eefe-469e-a6c4-faa7bf67d6a1","name":"CID10 revisado","value":"85c59095-eefe-469e-a6c4-faa7bf67d6a1:reviewed"},{"propertyId":"b4884c54-c88f-42f8-bf3c-adaa2e52f481","name":"CID9 + Específico","value":"698.0"},{"propertyId":"4a637756-3fd4-419b-9c84-31075135d8a3","name":"ICD11","value":"ME65.1"},{"propertyId":"1ccc2416-38f7-484c-967a-78dcf1f9bd12","name":"CID10 +Específicos","value":"L29.0"},{"propertyId":"f29c2d86-81fb-4ece-8375-bc1d89545af6","name":"CID11 revisado","value":"f29c2d86-81fb-4ece-8375-bc1d89545af6:reviewed"},{"propertyId":"cb6e1fc1-a673-4eab-8dec-4a483a473818","name":"SNOMED","value":"418363000"},{"propertyId":"b811b9b7-2aba-422b-9794-ae4633c837d9","name":"SNOMED revisado","value":"b811b9b7-2aba-422b-9794-ae4633c837d9:reviewed"}]},"statementId":"37","positiveProbability":0.45,"conclusionId":"e61a5a5b-2587-48ee-af32-49331f659810","lastEdited":1500999357637,"isActive":true,"obligatory":false},{"statement":{"statementId":"91","description":"Você teve febre ou se sentiu febril?","descriptionShort":"Febre / Sensação de febre","images":["https://api.mediktor.com/backoffice/downloads/File.Download?userId=04c35e41-6a8b-4541-44a3-cc20230ebdff&type=media&id=5f620ae9-80e5-4a46-bb29-189aa45b029d&d=1604063802270&b&l=1920"],"mediaFileList":[{"mediaURL":"https://api.mediktor.com/backoffice/downloads/File.Download?userId=04c35e41-6a8b-4541-44a3-cc20230ebdff&type=media&id=5f620ae9-80e5-4a46-bb29-189aa45b029d&d=1604063802270&b&l=1920","copyright":"© Copyright TeckelMedical","type":1}],"questionType":0,"descriptionLarge":"<p>Aumento da temperatura corporal. Quando aumenta alguns d&eacute;cimos acima de 37&ordm;C &eacute; chamada de febr&iacute;cula&nbsp;e quando ultrapassa 38&ordm;C j&aacute; &eacute; considerada febre. A pele geralmente est&aacute; quente ao toque e pode ser acompanhada de outros sintomas como fraqueza, dores musculares, dores nas articula&ccedil;&otilde;es, etc.</p>","descriptionExtended":"<p>Aumento da temperatura corporal. Quando aumenta alguns d&eacute;cimos acima de 37&ordm;C &eacute; chamada de febr&iacute;cula&nbsp;e quando ultrapassa 38&ordm;C j&aacute; &eacute; considerada febre. A pele geralmente est&aacute; quente ao toque e pode ser acompanhada de outros sintomas como fraqueza, dores musculares, dores nas articula&ccedil;&otilde;es, etc.</p>","hasDescriptionExtended":true,"categoryIdList":[],"propertyValueList":[{"propertyId":"dd165ff4-e848-4b3e-b7bb-cec77117b8a1","name":"CID9","value":"780.6"},{"propertyId":"b0c0d503-cc2a-4416-a53c-e10f465d4bf9","name":"CID9 revisado","value":"b0c0d503-cc2a-4416-a53c-e10f465d4bf9:reviewed"},{"propertyId":"85c59095-eefe-469e-a6c4-faa7bf67d6a1","name":"CID10 revisado","value":"85c59095-eefe-469e-a6c4-faa7bf67d6a1:reviewed"},{"propertyId":"4a637756-3fd4-419b-9c84-31075135d8a3","name":"ICD11","value":"MG26"},{"propertyId":"05c21681-3ff1-4c8c-bb0a-beba62984b6d","name":"CID10","value":"R50.9"},{"propertyId":"f29c2d86-81fb-4ece-8375-bc1d89545af6","name":"CID11 revisado","value":"f29c2d86-81fb-4ece-8375-bc1d89545af6:reviewed"},{"propertyId":"cb6e1fc1-a673-4eab-8dec-4a483a473818","name":"SNOMED","value":"386661006"},{"propertyId":"b811b9b7-2aba-422b-9794-ae4633c837d9","name":"SNOMED revisado","value":"b811b9b7-2aba-422b-9794-ae4633c837d9:reviewed"}]},"statementId":"91","positiveProbability":0.4,"conclusionId":"e61a5a5b-2587-48ee-af32-49331f659810","lastEdited":1570016497485,"isActive":true,"obligatory":false},{"statement":{"statementId":"p10092a","description":"Você tem irritação/infamação da faringe?","descriptionShort":"Irritação/Inflamação na faringe","images":["https://api.mediktor.com/backoffice/downloads/File.Download?userId=04c35e41-6a8b-4541-44a3-cc20230ebdff&type=media&id=9026d2c1-fb12-4bb3-bd30-d6c7dcdd482a&d=1605264518227&b&l=1920","https://api.mediktor.com/backoffice/downloads/File.Download?userId=04c35e41-6a8b-4541-44a3-cc20230ebdff&type=media&id=8b5a7c25-acbd-45d3-a417-cffcdb8476dc&d=1477779428028&b&l=1920"],"mediaFileList":[{"mediaURL":"https://api.mediktor.com/backoffice/downloads/File.Download?userId=04c35e41-6a8b-4541-44a3-cc20230ebdff&type=media&id=9026d2c1-fb12-4bb3-bd30-d6c7dcdd482a&d=1605264518227&b&l=1920","copyright":"© Copyright TeckelMedical","type":1},{"mediaURL":"https://api.mediktor.com/backoffice/downloads/File.Download?userId=04c35e41-6a8b-4541-44a3-cc20230ebdff&type=media&id=8b5a7c25-acbd-45d3-a417-cffcdb8476dc&d=1477779428028&b&l=1920","copyright":"© Copyright TeckelMedical","type":1}],"questionType":0,"descriptionLarge":"Por exemplo, como quando voc&ecirc; est&aacute; resfriado e tem dor de garganta e dificuldade para engolir.","descriptionExtended":"Por exemplo, como quando voc&ecirc; est&aacute; resfriado e tem dor de garganta e dificuldade para engolir.","hasDescriptionExtended":true,"categoryIdList":[],"propertyValueList":[{"propertyId":"dd165ff4-e848-4b3e-b7bb-cec77117b8a1","name":"CID9","value":"462"},{"propertyId":"b0c0d503-cc2a-4416-a53c-e10f465d4bf9","name":"CID9 revisado","value":"b0c0d503-cc2a-4416-a53c-e10f465d4bf9:reviewed"},{"propertyId":"85c59095-eefe-469e-a6c4-faa7bf67d6a1","name":"CID10 revisado","value":"85c59095-eefe-469e-a6c4-faa7bf67d6a1:reviewed"},{"propertyId":"4a637756-3fd4-419b-9c84-31075135d8a3","name":"ICD11","value":"CA02.Z"},{"propertyId":"05c21681-3ff1-4c8c-bb0a-beba62984b6d","name":"CID10","value":"J02.9"},{"propertyId":"f29c2d86-81fb-4ece-8375-bc1d89545af6","name":"CID11 revisado","value":"f29c2d86-81fb-4ece-8375-bc1d89545af6:reviewed"},{"propertyId":"cb6e1fc1-a673-4eab-8dec-4a483a473818","name":"SNOMED","value":"405737000"},{"propertyId":"b811b9b7-2aba-422b-9794-ae4633c837d9","name":"SNOMED revisado","value":"b811b9b7-2aba-422b-9794-ae4633c837d9:reviewed"}]},"statementId":"p10092a","positiveProbability":0.35,"conclusionId":"e61a5a5b-2587-48ee-af32-49331f659810","lastEdited":1559730569538,"isActive":true,"obligatory":false}],"triggeringFactors":[{"statement":{"statementId":"p2031","description":"Você acabou de se recuperar de uma infecção viral?","descriptionShort":"Infecção viral recente","images":[],"questionType":0,"descriptionLarge":"Infec&ccedil;&atilde;o recente causada por um v&iacute;rus.","descriptionExtended":"Infec&ccedil;&atilde;o recente causada por um v&iacute;rus.","hasDescriptionExtended":true,"categoryIdList":[],"propertyValueList":[{"propertyId":"dd165ff4-e848-4b3e-b7bb-cec77117b8a1","name":"CID9","value":"790.8"},{"propertyId":"b0c0d503-cc2a-4416-a53c-e10f465d4bf9","name":"CID9 revisado","value":"b0c0d503-cc2a-4416-a53c-e10f465d4bf9:reviewed"},{"propertyId":"85c59095-eefe-469e-a6c4-faa7bf67d6a1","name":"CID10 revisado","value":"85c59095-eefe-469e-a6c4-faa7bf67d6a1:reviewed"},{"propertyId":"4a637756-3fd4-419b-9c84-31075135d8a3","name":"ICD11","value":"1D9Z"},{"propertyId":"05c21681-3ff1-4c8c-bb0a-beba62984b6d","name":"CID10","value":"B34.9"},{"propertyId":"f29c2d86-81fb-4ece-8375-bc1d89545af6","name":"CID11 revisado","value":"f29c2d86-81fb-4ece-8375-bc1d89545af6:reviewed"},{"propertyId":"cb6e1fc1-a673-4eab-8dec-4a483a473818","name":"SNOMED","value":"34014006"},{"propertyId":"b811b9b7-2aba-422b-9794-ae4633c837d9","name":"SNOMED revisado","value":"b811b9b7-2aba-422b-9794-ae4633c837d9:reviewed"}]},"statementId":"p2031","positiveProbability":0.7,"conclusionId":"e61a5a5b-2587-48ee-af32-49331f659810","lastEdited":1497437641406,"isActive":true,"obligatory":false}],"level":0,"urgency":5,"urgencyEnum":0,"service":6,"common":false}}
```

Comment: I understand, in parts, I'm a little new with crawlers, I couldn't understand how you found the conclusionId and when I ran here the code got several jsons and in a certain conclusionID it started to give error, it may be because it finished and got all of them, but if it's not asking too much could you explain the code, how you got the vendor.js and everything else I really don't understand much

Comment: I understood how the site works, I found a request that provides a list of IDs.  to get it you need a token, to get it you need a code that is in the js file.  then we just pass the ID to the function and get the full json with all the information on the page.  what error occurred?

Comment: When I try to make the loop take all the IDs it returns this after a certain number(many) of iterations
`conclusion_list = get_conclusion_list(auth_token, device_id)
for conclusion in conclusion_list:
    print(get_details(conclusion, auth_token, device_id))`
OUTPUT:
`{"error":{"code":"ME667","description":"Invalid user ID token.","retry":true}}`

Comment: `Expired user identification token.` its the "description" camp without translation